# generate alternate number by twos in PHP for loops

Tags: php

I want to generate a number that will output something like 1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22 using PHP FOR loops. I tried odd and even number code but it doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
What I've done so far is :

```
$myNumber = 22;
for($myNumber = 1; mynumber <=22 ;$myNumber++){
if($myNumber % 2 )
echo $myNumber;
}
```

Comment: Can we see that `odd and even number code`? Maybe we can help you spot where it goes wrong

Comment: Show us what you've already done.

Comment: I've post my code. Please kindly help

Comment: Shouldn't `mynumber` be `$myNumber` in the middle of your `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this :

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<=7; $i++) {
    echo $i * 4 + 1 . "<br />";
    echo $i * 4 + 2 . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: yeah you are right! Thanks Benoit, what if I want to output 3,4,7,8,11,12,15,16,19,20? Thank you

Comment: Think about the multiplication and addition. Wrote your cases on a paper, and try to figure out, how to do that, based on this loop. I mean, use your brain for a while.

Comment: hey lolka_bolka do you think I will ask a question here If I know how to do it?